# How to get Facebook Debugger to read canonical URL?

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, seo, meta-tags

So this is happening when I test my website using Facebook's Open Graph Object Debugger:

[image]

It doesn't like the trailing numbers after the profile page. But I have both of these defined properly:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/profile/139">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.website.com/profile/139">
```

I've tried for hours and it just keeps redirecting to the homepage:

[image]

Is there anything I can add to my `.htaccess` file or PHP header to prevent this 301 redirect?

May be related to the way Facebook/Google handle URL parameters: http://gohe.ro/1fpOA0N

Comment: Find out what is causing this redirect, instead of trying to prevent it! If you want help with it, you'll need to provide what you already have as rules.

Comment: Can you provide actual url of your page , it would be easier for debugging.

Comment: Is it possible that you're redirecting users to mainpage if they don't have any user agents defined or javascript is disabled? Or is there any login procedures before seeing the profile pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anser was a problem with our domain host WP Engine, who tricks spiders into ignoring pure numeric strings at the end of page URL's. Pertains specifically to:

- Googlebot (Google's spider)
- Slurp! (Yahoo's spider)
- BingBot (Bing's spider)
- Facebook OG/Debugger

For example, the following URL:

http://www.website.com/profile/12345

Will be interpreted to these bots as:

http://www.website.com/profile

However, if the string is non-numeric the bots will recognize it. This is done for caching purposes. But again, this pertains only to WP Engine and a few other hosting providers.

Comment: This fixed it for us as well. We asked WP Engine and they disabled the "[Redirecting Bots](https://wpengine.com/support/redirecting-bots-how-this-benefits-you/)" option.  See the "When Should It Be Turned Off?" section in that article explaining the effect on Facebook's URL debugger. After they did so and we refreshed the cache and had the Facebook object debugger rescrape, the og:url kept the numeric ending and so the proper image and other metadata showed when sharing it. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me some head scratching. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Facebook treats the og:url Meta Tag as the Canonical for your page:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.yoursite.com/your-canonical-url" />
```

If your Canonical url is redirecting you are in fact creating a loop.
Don't redirect from your Canonical. 
Canonical is the page which should be considered the better option for the spiders.
If a page has a Canonical url tag it means that it is NOT the best/default page but rather it is a lesser variation of the Canocical.